# My RecyclerView couldnot view data from parse json ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i want to  make an application that get json response from server and set to my Recyclerview, but it contains error.

This is My code :

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_utama, container, false);

       recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_utra);
        dataku = new ArrayList<>();
        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4);
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), dataku);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        Ambildatadariserver(0);
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy){
                if(gridLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == dataku.size()-1){
                    Ambildatadariserver(dataku.get(dataku.size()-1).getId());
                }
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
    private void Ambildatadariserver(int id){
        AsyncTask<Integer, String, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, String, Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers){
                sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                String username = sharedPreferences.getString("username", "");
                String password = sharedPreferences.getString("password", "");
                httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
                RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder().add("username_krm", username).add("password_krm", password).build();
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url(alamat_json + integers[0]).post(formBody).build();
                try {
                    Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.body().string());
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        DataJson data = new DataJson(object.getInt("id"), object.getString("username"), object.getString("email"), object.getString("tanggal_lahir"));
                        dataku.add(data);
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (JSONException e){
                    System.out.println("Akhir Json File");
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void Avoid){
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
        task.execute();
    }
```

This is My log :

```
  01-22 20:47:42.830 10352-10366/? E/AndroidRuntime:  FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
          Process: ptguwatirtasejahtera.utraposmobile, PID: 10352
                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
                                                           at ptguwatirtasejahtera.utraposmobile.FragmentUtama$2.doInBackground(FragmentUtama.java:156)
                                                           at ptguwatirtasejahtera.utraposmobile.FragmentUtama$2.doInBackground(FragmentUtama.java:147)
                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                           at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Whats wrong, any ideas?, i am new to stackoverflow now.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Try logging `jsonArray` to see how it looks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two possilbe sources where the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException could have been thrown.
First the Adapter, I see dataku is a ArrayList, that has no Elements. Can the Adapter handle the empty list?
Second can findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() return -1, because then if the size of your list is 0, you try to access position -1 at dataku.get(dataku.size()-1).